# Postgres 100% CPU. High write/read ops count rate

Tags: postgresql

I have some issue with a DB (hosted on Amazon RDS), when sometimes 100% CPU consumption happens and all select queries became slow. Also there is a curious detail on graphs: write operations per sec is much greater than read operations per sec but `pg_stat_activity` returns only `select` queries, no `create`, `update` or `delete` (`CUD`) queries.

The question is: what is the cause of high write operations per sec metric value? Does this metric include operations with indexes (rebuild) on `CUD` queries? Why I don't see `CUD` queries in `pg_stat_activity` results?

[image]

Comment: This question is too broad and probably off topic for SO. I'd try [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two metrics (high CPU, much higher number of writes than reads) are probably unrelated (there doesn't seem to be any correlation between the two graphs).

High CPU utilisation can be caused by complex select queries, especially if there's a lot of in-memory sorting or filtering. Without details of the requests, it's difficult to say anything about what's going on.

More writes than reads probably just means that the dataset is effectively cached, so so there's no need for any data to be read from disk.

Note that `pg_stat_activity` will only give you a snapshot of activity. There may be write requests that are too short for them to be visible in a snapshot. Also, some `SELECT` queries may actually cause writes (the typical example is a call to `nextval`). There may also be logs being written to disk!

Comment: Thank you, actually it looks like high writes doesn't correlate with high CPU. I will take a look on heavy `SELECT` queries.